# modulo formula in C++

Tags: c++, combinatorics, modulo

I Have this formula:
(n - 1)! ((n (n - 1))/2 + ((n - 1) (n - 2))/4)
`2<=n<=100000`
I would like to modulate the result of this from this formula by any modulo, but for the moment let's assume that it is constant, `MOD = 999999997`. Unfortunately I can't just calculate the result and modulate it, because unfortunately I don't have variables larger than `2^64` at my disposal, so the main question is. What factors to modulate by MOD to get the results%MOD ?
Now let's assume that `n=19`. What is in brackets is equal to `247.5`

`18! = 6402373705728000`.
`(6402373705728000 * 247.5)mod999999997 = 921442488`.
Unfortunately, in case I modulate 18! first, the result will be wrong, because `(18!)mod999999997 = 724935119.    (724935119 * 247.5)mod9999997 = 421442490.`
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Isn't that more a math question than a C++ question? (Unless you are looking for means to represent and do computations with arbitrarily large numbers in C++, e.g. with some BigNum library).

Comment: Use a large number lib, or the Stirling approximation, or its log (provided that `x!` has many trailing zeroes when x is large, thus you can mitigate the approx). Also check the mod formulas everywhere on Google for x*y etc.

Comment: Use relationship  `(a * b) mod m` is the same as `((a mod m) * (b mod m)) mod m)` this will keep all the intermediate results within acceptable range

Comment: @RichardCritten Yeah, I was assuming something like that could be applied.

Comment: @user8593752 I see.  So it's a question how to mathematically work around programming language constraints ;-). Maybe we should have an SE numerics... we could turf all the floating point questions there!

Answer (score 0):

I think the sum could be break down. The only tricky part here is that `(n - 1)(n - 2)/4` may have a `.5` decimal., as `n(n-1) / 2` will always be integer.

```
S = (n - 1)!  * ((n (n - 1))/2 + ((n - 1) (n - 2))/4)
  = [(n-1)!  * (n*(n-1)/2)] + [(n-1)! * (n-1)(n-2)/4]
  = A + B
```

`A` is easy to do. With `B`, if `(n-1)(n-2) % 4 == 0` then there's nothing else either, else you can simplified to `X/2`, as `(n-1)(n-2)` is also divisible by 2.

If `n = 2`, it's trivial, else if `n > 2` there's always a 2 in the representation of `(N-1)! = 1x2x3x ... xN`. In that case, simply calculate `((N-1)!/2) = 1x3x4x5x ... xN`.

Late example:

```
N = 19
MOD = 999999997

--> 18! % MOD = 724935119 (1)
    (18!/2) % MOD = 862467558 (2)

    n(n-1)/2 = 171 (3)
    (n-1)(n-2)/2 = 153 (4)

--> S = (1)*(3) + (2)*(4) = 255921441723
    S % MOD = 921442488
```

On another note, if `mod` is some prime number, like `1e9+7`, you can just apply [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) to [calculate multiplicative inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098589/using-fermats-little-theorem-to-find-multiplicative-inverse) as such:

```
(a/b) % P = [(a%P) * ((b^(P-2)) % P)] % P (with P as prime, a and b are co-prime to P)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use 2 mathematical formulas here:

```
(a + b) mod c == (a mod c + b mod c) mod c
```

and

```
(a * b) mod c == (a mod c * b mod c) mod c
```

But those are only valid for integers. The nice part here is that formula can only be integer for n >= 2, provided you compute it as:

```
 (((n - 1)! * n * (n - 1))/2) + (((n - 1)! * (n - 1) * (n - 2))/4)
    1st part is integer       |         2nd part is too
```

for n == 2, first part boils down to 1 and second is 0

for n > 2 either n or n-1 is even so first part is integer, and again eithe n-1 of n-2 is even and (n-1)! is also even so second part is integer. As your formula can be rewritten to only use additions and multiplications it can be computed.

---

Here is a possible C++ code (before `unsigned long long` is required):

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Modop {
    T mod;

public:
    Modop(T mod) : mod(mod) {}

    T add(T a, T b) {
        return ((a % mod) + (b % mod)) % mod;
    }

    T mul(T a, T b) {
        return ((a % mod) * (b % mod)) % mod;
    }

    int fact_2(T n) {
        T cr = 1;
        for (T i = 3; i <= n; ++i) {
            cr = mul(cr, i);
        }
        return cr;
    }
};

template<class T>
T formula(T n, T mod) {
    Modop<T> op = mod;

    if (n == 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    T second, first = op.mul(op.fact_2(n - 1), op.mul(n, n - 1));
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        second = op.mul(op.fact_2(n - 1), op.mul((n - 2)/ 2, n - 1));
    }
    else {
        second = op.mul(op.fact_2(n - 1), op.mul(n- 2, (n - 1) / 2));
    }
    return op.add(first, second);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << formula(19ull, 999999997ull) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(n - 1)! / (n - k)!` is integer for 0 < k < n. You can use the above `Modop` class provided you generalize `fact_2` (from 3 to n) into a `fact_k(int n, int k)` giving `(k+1)...(n)` to directly compute that term.

Answer (score 0):

First of All , for n=2 we can say that the result is 1.
Then, the expression is equal to: (n*(n-1)*(n-1)!)/2 + (((n-1)*(n-2)/2)^2)*(n-3)! .

lemma: For every two consecutive integer number , one of them is even.

By lemma we can understand that n*(n-1) is even and also (n-1)*(n-2) is even too. So we know that the answer is an integer number.

First we calculate (n*(n-1)*(n-1)!)/2 modulo MOD. We can calculate (n*(n-1))/2 that can be saved in a long long variable like x, and we get the mod of it modulo MOD:

```
x = (n*(n-1))/2;
x %= MOD;
```

After that for: i (n-1 -> 1) we do:

```
x = (x*i)%MOD;
```

And we know that both of 'x' and 'i' are less than MOD and the result of
multiplication can be save in a long long variable.

And likewise we do the same for (((n-1)*(n-2)/2)^2)*(n-3)! .
We calculate (n-1)*(n-2)/2 that can be save in a long long variable like y, and we get the mod of it modulo MOD:

```
y = ((n-1)*(n-2))/2;
y %= MOD;
```

And after that we replace (y^2)%MOD on y because we know that y is less than MOD and y*y can be save in a long long variable:

```
y = (y*y)%MOD;
```

Then like before for: i (n-3 -> 1) we do:

```
y = (y*i)%MOD;
```

And finally the answer is (x+y)%MOD